Can't launch the App from Google Assistant in Android
I was trying to launch my application from Google Assistant. They say that we need to publish our application and nothing else is required.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/overview#app_actions
So, I have published my application for internal testing to verify this. After downloading that application from Play Store link, I tried launching the application but that isn't working. Does publishing it for internal testing doesn't work?

Try it after publishing it to production also consider reading this post.

@BobSmith, I checked the settings whatever is mentioned in this link. But still my application doesn't get launched.  I have also added the some BII's added in shortcuts.xml as mentioned here-- https://github.com/android/app-actions-samples/tree/main/common-biis
But still launching via Google Assistant doesn't work. I just want to launch my application via Google Assistant. Similar how we say "Open Outlook" it launches that app.

How can we first publish the application before testing this internally? There should be something right?

The GitHub repo you have referred is now depreciated. Try finding some other alternatives.

Ok I will look for that. But testing whether this works or not? We will first internally test it right? Why would someone publish the application public before checking this?

yes correct but make sure you upload release build in internal track

I have uploaded the release build only @BobSmith and still it doesn't work for me

You may set bounty to your question so that more audience can help you or can try other alternate option to achieve it.
